# Ignore some the npm dependencies in package.json for jenkins build

Tags: node.js, cordova, jenkins, npm

I am developing a cordova application and i am performing  a jenkins build for continuous integration.Jenkins uses npm build for installing the dependencies and creating the build.

This is my package-json

```
"dependencies": {
    "com-darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent": "git+https://github.com/darryncampbell/darryncampbell-cordova-plugin-intent.git",
    "com.borismus.webintent": "https://github.com/cordova-misc/cordova-webintent.git",
    "com.hutchind.cordova.plugins.streamingmedia": "~0.1.4",
     }
```

I want to ignore first two dependencies just only for build but i need those for running my project.

Is there anyway to ignore some of the dependencies only for the build